# replace image when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two tables, the first one (id=symbols) contains the 3 images. 
The second table (id=tbl) will contain a variety of different images.

I am trying to replace the image of a cell (for this example lets say its the second cell from the right on the top row) with the one selected from the symbol table.

I would like to highlight the images in the symbol table when hovering over them.
When clicked I would like to replace the image in the other table with the image being clicked and also change the background color of the table cell that contains the chosen image.
I will also need to be able to identify which image (or cell) was clicked.

Here is my current fiddle not working too well http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/70/.

Thanks for the help.

```
<table id="symbols">
<tr>
<td  ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Yellow-icon.png"/></td>
  <td  >
      <img src=" http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Blue-icon.png"/>

  </td>
  <td class="items  p1 p3"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/32/social-google-buzz-button-icon.png"/></td>      
  </tr>
</table>  

<table border="1" id="tbl">
<tr>
  <td ></td>
  <td  bgcolor=#000000 >
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png"/>
  </td>
  <td class="items  p1 p3"></td>      
  </tr>

  <tr>      
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  <td class="items  p1"></td>
  <td class="items p3" bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>      
  <td class="piece" id="p1" ></td>
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
    <td class="piece" id="p3" ></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

jquery

```
  var imgs = $('img');

  imgs.click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
    $("#tbl").find("tbody tr").eq(2).children().first().attr('src', img);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way.. http://jsfiddle.net/4Ym43/

```
var imgs = $('img'); 

imgs.click(function(){
  var img = $(this); 
    $("#tbl").find("tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(1) img").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
  //The cells we can move our image to.

});
```

although i'd rather use id's or classes

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way I can also get the image name or ID or the image clicked? Thanks.